# Access to the path \\server\folder\subfolder\..\file_log is denied

Tags: c#

I wanted to write the log to the server. The following code is going to create a log file and record the details.

```
private Log in_log;
in_log = new Log(logfolder + call_date.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "\\" + call_number + ".log");
```

But I got an exception.

```
Access to the path '\\10.50.96.221\inbox\messagelogs\20131105\HZ1_20131105132956319_59.log' is denied.
```

However I can access the folder `\\10.50.96.221\inbox\messagelogs\20131105`.
My permission is "Administrators;Remote Desktop Users".

What is wrong?

Comment: Is this a web application or WinForms application? If it is a web application make sure the application pool identity (usaly IIS_IUSRS) has write permittion. if a Win Forms and your on Vista/7/2008/r2/2012 try runnin the application as an admistrator (it is a context option in the righclick dropdown)

Comment: It is a windows service.

Comment: Does the account the service is running under have write permissions to that location? Based off the URI being an IP address I am taking it your running a service on one machine to write to another? If that is the case remember that even though the computers may have the same Users created on them, unless those users are domain users the accounts are technically different.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I run the service on my desktop and write the log on the server. The server has two domains.What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean the server has two domains?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, I saw the users in control panel. I am in the domain "XXX". The "Admin" is in the domain "machine01" something like.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40585/discussion-between-love-and-eagle-f90)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The windows service runs under its own user. Verify that that user has access to the remote just as your user has. Or change the user to be your user when the service runs.

Comment: I heard that I have to right click the property of the service and logon as 'Network Service'. But I still failed.

Answer (score 0):

Your computers are not on a a windows domain, so you have two options. Only 1 of which I have confidance will work:

1. (this works 99% of the time) Grant "All Users" write permission on the folder
2. (Never tried it but in theory it should work) In the properties of the service, goto Login, chose "This Account" -> Browser -> Locations. If you see the server computer there you should be able to chose that location and add the admin account from the server as the user the Service runs under.